# Call Controller Method with Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, controller

Is it possible to call a method of a plugin's controller from within a plugin? I don't plan on making a habit of this but sometimes it may be needed. Just trying to plan ahead.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just off-load that logic into a service, and simply make the service accessible instead?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
`craft()->runController('pluginHandle/controllerId/action');`
```

Although I'd question the decisions you've made to get to the point where you had to ask this question. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't needed to do this yet and yes of course I want to avoid it. What I'm thinking is if I have a controller that does a **thing**, and I have zero time to refactor that process into a service, then I might as well just call the controller.